# Which is the correct word to use here: "consensus" or "majority"?

Tags: word-choice, differences

I was just told that:

> What you call a consensus isn't a consensus, but a majority.

He implied that it was not a consensus because a few disagreed with the decision made. From my understanding, consensus does not require unanimity. For example, when we talk about a scientific consensus, there might be a few dissenters, but not many.

Is that correct?

Comment: IMO, *consensus* implies a rather vast majority, while *majority* just means anything more than fifty percent.

Comment: @Peter Agreed -- I think of consensus as "nearly complete" agreement.

Comment: Sounds like an ideological debate... so your reply is (if accurate) something like "OK, if you like, *overwhelming majority*"

Comment: @jgbelacqua: It isn't. It was a normal conversation, but my interlocutor got stuck on my use of the word consensus for some odd reason.

Comment: Ha. Well, I've been guilty of such obsessiveness myself, I suppose.  In any case, I think that your understanding (of the usage) appears to be correct.

Comment: "Consensus" implies that more than 50% of those involved are "reasonable", in the true sense of the term.  "Majority" implies that a group that comprised more than 50% got their way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While **consensus** is not necessarily a unanimous stance, it is usually a vast majority - nearing complete agreement. I would expect a rate of 80% or more if someone said that an opinion was *consensus*.

**Majority** simply means the larger part. That is why a lot of companies have an owner with a *majority share* of 51%; so that under any circumstances they will always own the larger part of the company. It doesn't matter that the difference is so small (51-49% is just 2%) - if it is larger, it is a majority.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

*Consensus* means "general agreement," while *majority* means "the greater number."

The NOAD reports the following note, about the usage of *majority*.

> *Majority* means more than half: *fifty-one out of a hundred is a majority*. A *plurality* is the largest number among three or more. Consider the following scenarios: If Anne received 50 votes, Barry received 30, and Carlos received 20, then Anne received a plurality, and no candidate won a majority. If Anne got 35 votes, Barry 14, and Carlos 51, then Carlos won both the plurality and the majority .

Comment: Could you explain what NOAD is?

Comment: New Oxford American Dictionary. Basically, the regional (incorrect ;)) version of the Oxford English Dictionary.

Comment: @Daniel: 'regional'? Oh...-that- region.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that consensus does not necessarily imply unanimity.

ISO, IEC, CEN, CENELEC, and various national standards bodies use the following definition of *consensus* for the purposes of standardization and related activities:

> **consensus**
>   general agreement, characterized by the absence of sustained opposition to substantial issues by any important part of the concerned interests and by a process that involves seeking to take into account the views of all parties concerned and to reconcile any conflicting arguments
>   NOTE Consensus need not imply unanimity.

(This definition might be applicable to meta-discussions of Stack Exchange websites, too.)